# shadows are lost while Java3D 1.5.2 to 1.7.0 migration

Tags: java, migration, java-3d

Strange behavior was appeared while migrating from Java3D 1.5.2 to 1.7.0.

Looks like shadows are lost in new version of Java3D:

the first picture created with Java3D 1.5.2 (based on j3dcore-ogl.dll)
[first_picture_link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj0G9.png)

the second picture created with Java3D 1.7.0 (based on gluegen-rt-2.3.2.jar and jogl-all-2.3.2.jar)
[second_picture_link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBYSu.png)

The same code was used for both cases.

Why does it happen?
I can't believe that this hard downgrade is possible, may be some configurations should be change etc.

UPDATED 01.09.22
Code (imports for Java3D 1.7.0):

```
import org.jogamp.java3d.*;
import org.jogamp.java3d.utils.behaviors.keyboard.KeyNavigatorBehavior;
import org.jogamp.java3d.utils.behaviors.mouse.MouseRotate;
import org.jogamp.java3d.utils.behaviors.mouse.MouseWheelZoom;
import org.jogamp.java3d.utils.geometry.GeometryInfo;
import org.jogamp.java3d.utils.geometry.NormalGenerator;
import org.jogamp.java3d.utils.universe.PlatformGeometry;
import org.jogamp.java3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;
import org.jogamp.vecmath.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Plate {

    int jagged;
    private String currentShapeID = null;
    private SimpleUniverse universe = null;
    private Canvas3D canvas = null;
    private TransformGroup viewtrans = null;

    private TransformGroup tg = null;
    private Transform3D t3d = null;
    private JPanel canvasPanel;

    public Plate() {
        canvasPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, canvasPanel);
        f.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Plate().paint3D();
    }

    public void paint3D() {
        set3dLoadedStatus();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GraphicsConfiguration config = SimpleUniverse
                            .getPreferredConfiguration();

                    canvas = new Canvas3D(config);

                    universe = new SimpleUniverse(canvas);


                    universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();

                    universe.getViewer().getView().setBackClipDistance(10.0);

                    BranchGroup scene = new BranchGroup();

                    BoundingSphere bounds = new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(), 10000.0);

                    viewtrans = universe.getViewingPlatform().getViewPlatformTransform();

                    KeyNavigatorBehavior keyNavBeh = new KeyNavigatorBehavior(viewtrans);
                    keyNavBeh.setSchedulingBounds(bounds);
                    PlatformGeometry platformGeom = new PlatformGeometry();
                    platformGeom.addChild(keyNavBeh);
                    universe.getViewingPlatform().setPlatformGeometry(platformGeom);

                    BranchGroup objRoot = new BranchGroup();
                    objRoot.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);
                    objRoot.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_CHILDREN_WRITE);
                    objRoot.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_CHILDREN_READ);
                    tg = new TransformGroup();
                    t3d = new Transform3D();

                    tg.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);

                    t3d.setTranslation(new Vector3d(-0.15, -0.3, -5.0));
                    t3d.setRotation(new AxisAngle4f(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f));
                    t3d.setScale(getInitialScale());

                    tg.setTransform(t3d);


                    objRoot.addChild(tg);



                    int jagged = getJagged();
                    double[] rectDip = getRectDip();

                    int boxX = 16;

                    createVoxelizedShape(tg, boxX, jagged, rectDip);

                    float directionalPower = 0.55f;

                    final Color3f color3f = new Color3f(directionalPower, directionalPower, directionalPower);

                    DirectionalLight directionalLight = new DirectionalLight(true, color3f, new Vector3f(-0.3f, 0.2f, -1.0f));

                    directionalLight.setInfluencingBounds(new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(), 10000.0));

                    objRoot.addChild(directionalLight);


                    AmbientLight ambientLight = new AmbientLight(true, new Color3f(1f - directionalPower, 1f - directionalPower, 1f - directionalPower));

                    ambientLight.setInfluencingBounds(new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(), 10000.0));

                    objRoot.addChild(ambientLight);


                    MouseRotate myMouseRotate = new MouseRotate();
                    myMouseRotate.setTransformGroup(tg);
                    myMouseRotate.setSchedulingBounds(new BoundingSphere());
                    objRoot.addChild(myMouseRotate);

                    MouseWheelZoom mouseWheelZoom = new MouseWheelZoom();
                    mouseWheelZoom.setTransformGroup(tg);
                    mouseWheelZoom.setSchedulingBounds(tg.getBounds());
                    objRoot.addChild(mouseWheelZoom);
                    objRoot.compile();

                    scene.addChild(objRoot);

                    Background background = new Background();
                    background.setColor(getBackgroundColor());
                    background.setApplicationBounds(bounds);
                    scene.addChild(background);
                    universe.addBranchGraph(scene);

                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                        try {
                            canvasPanel.removeAll();
                            canvasPanel.add(canvas);
                            canvasPanel.repaint();
                            canvasPanel.revalidate();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            set3dLoadedStatus("<html>ERROR: " + e.getMessage() + "</html>");
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                        set3dLoadedStatus("something went wrong, try again");
                    });
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();
    }

    private double getInitialScale() {
        return 3;
    }

    protected int getJagged() {
        return 1;
    }

    protected double[] getRectDip() {

        return new double[]{1, 1, 1};
    }

    protected void set3dLoadedStatus() {
        set3dLoadedStatus("3D model is loading ...");
    }

    protected void set3dLoadedStatus(String message) {
        canvasPanel.removeAll();
        canvasPanel.add(new JLabel(message));
        canvasPanel.repaint();
        canvasPanel.revalidate();
    }

    public void createVoxelizedShape(TransformGroup tg, int boxX, int jagged, double[] rectDip) {
        this.jagged = jagged;

        double gridspace = 1.0 / boxX;

        double xr, yr, zr;
        double rectScaleX, rectScaleY, rectScaleZ;
        int xj, yj, zj;

        rectScaleX = rectDip[0];
        rectScaleY = rectDip[1];
        rectScaleZ = rectDip[2];

        double gridSpaceX = gridspace * rectScaleX;
        double gridSpaceY = gridspace * rectScaleY;
        double gridSpaceZ = gridspace * rectScaleZ;


        ArrayList<Point3d> point3dArrayList = new ArrayList<Point3d>();

        int boxY = getBoxY(boxX, rectScaleX, rectScaleY, rectScaleZ, jagged);
        int boxZ = getBoxZ(boxX, rectScaleX, rectScaleY, rectScaleZ, jagged);


        for (int k = 0; k < boxZ; k++)
            for (int j = 0; j < boxY; j++)
                for (int i = 0; i < boxX; i++) {
                    xj = 2 * jagged * (i / jagged) + jagged - boxX;
                    yj = 2 * jagged * (j / jagged) + jagged - boxY;
                    zj = 2 * jagged * (k / jagged) + jagged - boxZ;
                    /* all the following coordinates should be scaled by the same sizeX. So we scale xj,yj,zj by 2boxX with extra
                     * ratio for rectangular dipoles. Thus, yr and zr are not necessarily in fixed ranges (like from -1/2 to 1/2).
                     * This is done to treat adequately cases when particle dimensions are the same (along different axes), but e.g.
                     * boxY!=boxX (so there are some extra void dipoles). All anisotropies in the particle itself are treated in
                     * the specific shape modules below (see e.g. ELLIPSOID).
                     */
                    xr = (0.5 * xj) / boxX;
                    yr = (0.5 * yj) / boxX * (rectScaleY / rectScaleX);
                    zr = (0.5 * zj) / boxX * (rectScaleZ / rectScaleX);

                    if (isPointInsideShapeVolume(xr, yr, zr)) {
                        addVoxel(xr, yr, zr, gridSpaceX, gridSpaceY, gridSpaceZ, point3dArrayList);
                    }
                }


        if (point3dArrayList.size() < 1) {
            return;
        }

        ArrayList<Double> points = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (Point3d point3d : point3dArrayList) {
            points.add(point3d.x);
            points.add(point3d.y);
            points.add(point3d.z);
        }

        GeometryInfo gi = new GeometryInfo(GeometryInfo.QUAD_ARRAY);
        gi.setCoordinates(points.stream().mapToDouble(i -> i).toArray());
        NormalGenerator normalGenerator = new NormalGenerator();
        normalGenerator.generateNormals(gi);
        Appearance ap = new Appearance();
        PolygonAttributes polyAttrbutes = new PolygonAttributes();
        polyAttrbutes.setPolygonMode(PolygonAttributes.POLYGON_FILL);
        polyAttrbutes.setCullFace(PolygonAttributes.CULL_NONE);
        ap.setPolygonAttributes(polyAttrbutes);
        Material material = new Material();
        material.setShininess(50f);
        material.setAmbientColor(getVoxelColor());
        material.setDiffuseColor(getVoxelColor());
        ap.setMaterial(material);


        Shape3D shape1 = new Shape3D(gi.getGeometryArray(), ap);
        tg.addChild(shape1);

        ap = new Appearance();
        polyAttrbutes = new PolygonAttributes();
        polyAttrbutes.setPolygonMode(PolygonAttributes.POLYGON_LINE);
        polyAttrbutes.setCullFace(PolygonAttributes.CULL_NONE);
        ap.setPolygonAttributes(polyAttrbutes);
        material = new Material();
        material.setShininess(50f);
        material.setDiffuseColor(getVoxelLineColor());
        material.setAmbientColor(getVoxelLineColor());
        ap.setMaterial(material);
        Shape3D shape2 = new Shape3D(gi.getGeometryArray(), ap);
        tg.addChild(shape2);
    }


    public int getBoxY(int boxX, double rectScaleX, double rectScaleY, double rectScaleZ, int jagged) {
        return fitBox_yz(boxX * (rectScaleX / rectScaleY), jagged);
    }


    public int getBoxZ(int boxX, double rectScaleX, double rectScaleY, double rectScaleZ, int jagged) {
        return fitBox_yz((firstParam + 1) * boxX * (rectScaleX / rectScaleZ), jagged);
    }

    double firstParam = 0.5;

    protected boolean isPointInsideShapeVolume(double xr, double yr, double zr) {
        double ro2 = xr * xr + yr * yr;
        if (ro2 <= 0.25) {
            double tmp1 = Math.abs(zr) - firstParam * 0.5;
            if (tmp1 <= 0 || tmp1 * tmp1 + ro2 <= 0.25) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void addVoxel(double xr, double yr, double zr, double gridSpaceX, double gridSpaceY, double gridSpaceZ, ArrayList<Point3d> point3dArrayList) {
        Point3d point1 = new Point3d(xr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);
        Point3d point2 = new Point3d(xr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);
        Point3d point3 = new Point3d(xr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);
        Point3d point4 = new Point3d(xr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);

        Point3d point5 = new Point3d(xr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);
        Point3d point6 = new Point3d(xr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);
        Point3d point7 = new Point3d(xr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);
        Point3d point8 = new Point3d(xr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);


        point3dArrayList.add(point1);
        point3dArrayList.add(point2);
        point3dArrayList.add(point3);
        point3dArrayList.add(point4);
        point3dArrayList.add(point5);
        point3dArrayList.add(point6);
        point3dArrayList.add(point7);
        point3dArrayList.add(point8);


        Point3d point9 = new Point3d(xr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);
        Point3d point10 = new Point3d(xr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);
        Point3d point11 = new Point3d(xr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);
        Point3d point12 = new Point3d(xr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);

        Point3d point13 = new Point3d(xr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);
        Point3d point14 = new Point3d(xr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);
        Point3d point15 = new Point3d(xr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);
        Point3d point16 = new Point3d(xr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);

        point3dArrayList.add(point9);
        point3dArrayList.add(point10);
        point3dArrayList.add(point11);
        point3dArrayList.add(point12);
        point3dArrayList.add(point13);
        point3dArrayList.add(point14);
        point3dArrayList.add(point15);
        point3dArrayList.add(point16);


        Point3d point17 = new Point3d(xr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);
        Point3d point18 = new Point3d(xr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);
        Point3d point19 = new Point3d(xr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);
        Point3d point20 = new Point3d(xr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);

        Point3d point21 = new Point3d(xr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);
        Point3d point22 = new Point3d(xr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);
        Point3d point23 = new Point3d(xr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);
        Point3d point24 = new Point3d(xr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceX, yr + jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceY, zr - jagged * 0.5 * gridSpaceZ);

        point3dArrayList.add(point17);
        point3dArrayList.add(point18);
        point3dArrayList.add(point19);
        point3dArrayList.add(point20);
        point3dArrayList.add(point21);
        point3dArrayList.add(point22);
        point3dArrayList.add(point23);
        point3dArrayList.add(point24);
    }

    public static int fitBox(int box, int jagged) {
        return jagged * ((box + jagged - 1) / jagged);
    }

    public static int fitBox_yz(double size, int jagged)
        /* given the size of the particle in y or z direction (in units of dipoles), finds the closest grid size, which would
         * satisfy the FitBox function. The rounding is performed so to minimize the maximum difference between the stack of
         * dipoles and corresponding particle dimension.
         * The distance between the center of the outer super-dipole (J^3 original dipoles) and the particle (enclosing box)
         * boundary is between 0.25 and 0.75 of super-dipole size, corresponding to the discretization along the x-axis, for
         * which the optimum distance of 0.5 (the dipole cube fits tight into the boundary) is automatically satisfied.
         *
         * !!! However, it is still possible that the whole outer layer of dipoles would be void because the estimate does not
         * take into account the details of the shape e.g. its curvature. For instance, 'adda -grid 4 -shape ellipsoid 1 2.13'
         * results in grid 4x4x9, but the layers z=0, z=8 will be void. This is because the dipole centers in this layers always
         * have non-zero x and y coordinates (at least half-dipole in absolute value) and do not fall inside the ellipsoid,
         * although the points {+-4,0,0} do fall into it.
         */ {
        return jagged * (int) Math.round(size / jagged);
    }


    public Color3f getBackgroundColor() {
        return new Color3f(0.75f, 0.69f, 0.680f);
    }

    protected Color3f getVoxelColor() {
        return new Color3f(255, 0, 255);
    }

    protected Color3f getVoxelLineColor() {
        return new Color3f(0, 0, 0);
    }


    protected Color3f getSurfaceColor() {
        return new Color3f(255, 0, 255);
    }

    ;

    protected String error;

    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to use values in range [0.0f; 1.0f] for a color,

for Java3D 1.7.0 Color3f(255, 0 , 0) is not acceptable, the better way is to replace it with Color3f(0.75f, 0 , 0)